# How to get current HDD type?

Tags: vb6, wmi, master-slave, hard-drive

I've found a way to get hdd serial no in vb6. But it needs to select an option from

- primary master
- primary slave
- secondary master
- secondary slave

But I want to auto select an option. The auto select logic is,

> suppose I've 4 HDD with the above 4 types. And the logic will select the hdd type, on which the current system is loaded.

I really have no idea how to detect the current system is on which HDD type. Please help.

Here is the class that I use to select HDD serial no. [HDSN CLASS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbpowerpacks/thread/0e9a097d-c22c-4b70-ad50-106d680fa5b3/#eceda6cb-1508-4d90-b79e-83bd02323869)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should help:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const FILE_SHARE_READ = &H1
Private Const FILE_SHARE_WRITE = &H2
Private Const GENERIC_READ = &H80000000
Private Const GENERIC_WRITE = &H40000000
Private Const OPEN_EXISTING = 3

Private Const IOCTL_VOLUME_BASE     As Long = 86 ' Asc("V")
Private Const METHOD_BUFFERED       As Long = 0
Private Const FILE_READ_ACCESS      As Long = 1
Private Const FILE_ANY_ACCESS       As Long = 0

'DEFINE IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS CTL_CODE(IOCTL_VOLUME_BASE, 0, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
Private Const IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS = (((IOCTL_VOLUME_BASE) * (2& ^ 16&)) Or ((FILE_ANY_ACCESS) * (2& ^ 14&)) Or ((0&) * (2& ^ 2&)) Or (METHOD_BUFFERED))

Private Type DISK_EXTENT
    DiskNumber          As Long
    StartingOffset      As Currency
    ExtentLength        As Currency
End Type

Private Type VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS
    NumberOfDiskExtents As Currency
    Extents(1 To 4)     As DISK_EXTENT
End Type

Private Declare Function CreateFile _
    Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateFileA" _
    (ByVal lpFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
    ByVal dwShareMode As Long, _
    ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As Long, _
    ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
    ByVal hTemplateFile As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CloseHandle _
    Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowsDirectory Lib "Kernel32.dll" Alias "GetWindowsDirectoryW" ( _
    ByVal lpBuffer As Long, _
    ByVal uSize As Long _
) As Long

Private Declare Function DeviceIoControlNoInput _
    Lib "kernel32" Alias "DeviceIoControl" _
    (ByVal hDevice As Long, _
    ByVal dwIoControlCode As Long, _
    ByVal lpInBuffer As Long, _
    ByVal nInBufferSize As Long, _
    ByRef lpOutBuffer As Any, _
    ByVal nOutBufferSize As Long, _
    ByRef lpBytesReturned As Long, _
    ByVal lpOverlapped As Long) As Long

' Return the index of the physical drive from which we've booted into Windows. 
Public Function GetBootPhysicalDrive() As Long

    Dim sWindowsPath        As String
    Dim nRet                As Long
    Dim sDevicePath         As String
    Dim hLogicalBootDrive   As Long
    Dim sVolumeDevice       As String
    Dim uVolumeDiskExtents  As VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS
    Dim nBytesReturned      As Long

    ' Allocate space and retrieve the windows directory.
    sWindowsPath = Space$(64)
    nRet = GetWindowsDirectory(StrPtr(sWindowsPath), 64)

    ' This gives us the volume that Windows is on. Open it.
    sVolumeDevice = "\\.\" & Left$(sWindowsPath, 2)
    hLogicalBootDrive = CreateFile(sVolumeDevice, GENERIC_READ + GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ + FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0&, OPEN_EXISTING, 0&, 0&)

    ' Find out information about this volume.
    nRet = DeviceIoControlNoInput(hLogicalBootDrive, IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS, 0&, 0&, uVolumeDiskExtents, LenB(uVolumeDiskExtents), nBytesReturned, 0&)

    If nRet = 0 Then
    ' Something went wrong. Return error value.
        GetBootPhysicalDrive = -1
    Else
    ' This is the physical disk number.
        GetBootPhysicalDrive = uVolumeDiskExtents.Extents(1).DiskNumber
    End If

    ' Close volume.
    CloseHandle hLogicalBootDrive

End Function
```

Comment: Hay I got it. `Public Function GetDiskSerialNumber() As String
    Dim wmiObject As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    
    Set wmiObject = GetObject("WinMgmts:")
    For Each obj In wmiObject.InstancesOf("Win32_PhysicalMedia")
        If obj.Tag = "\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE" + CStr(GetBootPhysicalDrive) Then GetDiskSerialNumber = obj.SerialNumber
    Next obj
End Function`

Answer (score 0):

Using the[Above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861318/how-to-get-current-hdd-type/11875423#11875423) Solution of Mark Bertenshaw I wrote the following in a module and just called the `GetDiskSerialNumber` function to get serial of the HDD from which the current system is Booted. Here is my module code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const FILE_SHARE_READ = &H1
Private Const FILE_SHARE_WRITE = &H2
Private Const GENERIC_READ = &H80000000
Private Const GENERIC_WRITE = &H40000000
Private Const OPEN_EXISTING = 3

Private Const IOCTL_VOLUME_BASE     As Long = 86 ' Asc("V")
Private Const METHOD_BUFFERED       As Long = 0
Private Const FILE_READ_ACCESS      As Long = 1
Private Const FILE_ANY_ACCESS       As Long = 0

'DEFINE IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS CTL_CODE(IOCTL_VOLUME_BASE, 0, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
Private Const IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS = (((IOCTL_VOLUME_BASE) * (2& ^ 16&)) Or ((FILE_ANY_ACCESS) * (2& ^ 14&)) Or ((0&) * (2& ^ 2&)) Or (METHOD_BUFFERED))

Private Type DISK_EXTENT
    DiskNumber          As Long
    StartingOffset      As Currency
    ExtentLength        As Currency
End Type

Private Type VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS
    NumberOfDiskExtents As Currency
    Extents(1 To 4)     As DISK_EXTENT
End Type

Private Declare Function CreateFile _
    Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateFileA" _
    (ByVal lpFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
    ByVal dwShareMode As Long, _
    ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As Long, _
    ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
    ByVal hTemplateFile As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CloseHandle _
    Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowsDirectory Lib "Kernel32.dll" Alias "GetWindowsDirectoryW" ( _
    ByVal lpBuffer As Long, _
    ByVal uSize As Long _
) As Long

Private Declare Function DeviceIoControlNoInput _
    Lib "kernel32" Alias "DeviceIoControl" _
    (ByVal hDevice As Long, _
    ByVal dwIoControlCode As Long, _
    ByVal lpInBuffer As Long, _
    ByVal nInBufferSize As Long, _
    ByRef lpOutBuffer As Any, _
    ByVal nOutBufferSize As Long, _
    ByRef lpBytesReturned As Long, _
    ByVal lpOverlapped As Long) As Long

' Return the index of the physical drive from which we've booted into Windows. 
Public Function GetBootPhysicalDrive() As Long

    Dim sWindowsPath        As String
    Dim nRet                As Long
    Dim sDevicePath         As String
    Dim hLogicalBootDrive   As Long
    Dim sVolumeDevice       As String
    Dim uVolumeDiskExtents  As VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS
    Dim nBytesReturned      As Long

    ' Allocate space and retrieve the windows directory.
    sWindowsPath = Space$(64)
    nRet = GetWindowsDirectory(StrPtr(sWindowsPath), 64)

    ' This gives us the volume that Windows is on. Open it.
    sVolumeDevice = "\\.\" & Left$(sWindowsPath, 2)
    hLogicalBootDrive = CreateFile(sVolumeDevice, GENERIC_READ + GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ + FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0&, OPEN_EXISTING, 0&, 0&)

    ' Find out information about this volume.
    nRet = DeviceIoControlNoInput(hLogicalBootDrive, IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS, 0&, 0&, uVolumeDiskExtents, LenB(uVolumeDiskExtents), nBytesReturned, 0&)

    If nRet = 0 Then
    ' Something went wrong. Return error value.
        GetBootPhysicalDrive = -1
    Else
    ' This is the physical disk number.
        GetBootPhysicalDrive = uVolumeDiskExtents.Extents(1).DiskNumber
    End If

    ' Close volume.
    CloseHandle hLogicalBootDrive

End Function

Public Function GetDiskSerialNumber() As String
    Dim wmiObject As Object
    Dim obj As Object

    Set wmiObject = GetObject("WinMgmts:")
    For Each obj In wmiObject.InstancesOf("Win32_PhysicalMedia")
        If obj.Tag = "\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE" + CStr(GetBootPhysicalDrive) Then GetDiskSerialNumber = obj.Tag + " : " + obj.SerialNumber
    Next obj
End Function
```

Many thanks to [Mark Bertenshaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127742/mark-bertenshaw).